# Why does 'not in' return True with 2-dimensional lists that contain the cited value in their inner lists

Tags: python, list, boolean

I want this statement to return False. Clearly there are plenty of 0s in the list, however it returns True.

```
zeros = [[0] * 8] * 8 
print(0 not in zeros) 
# True
```

Could someone explain this behaviour?
Also, is there a different expression I can use that will evaluate to False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `zeros`:

```
>>> zeros
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

All the elements of `zeros` are `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.  None of them are just `0`.

If you simply want a statement that will evaluate to `False` there is of course:

```
>>> print(False)
False
```

but if you want to specifically test if there are not any `0`s in any of the elements of `zeros` you could do:

```
>>> print(not any(0 in z for z in zeros))
False
```

Comment: >>> print(not any(0 in z for z in zeros))
False

This is what I was trying to do. And now I understand the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator only looks at the elements of `zeros`, and these are `[0]` and not `0`. Therefore it returns false. You could convert it into a `numpy.array`, for which the `in` operator is defined as you would need it.

```
from numpy import array
zeros = array([[0] * 8] * 8) 
print(0 not in zeros) 
# False
```

Just be aware, if the array is of floating point type, you need to test for `0.0` instead.

Comment: Just to comment, before anybody else smears it into my face: You would never write `zeros = array([[0] * 8] * 8) ` ... I assume your actual application is another 2D array anyhow.